# Add layer info to points, keeps failing in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, csv, spatial-join

Within QGIS, I am looking to get an extra column in the points file, describing in which layer the point lies.

- All points are within 1 layer:
  [Layer source](https://statbel.fgov.be/nl/open-data/statistische-sectoren) >SHP file from shapefile.zip.
- Validate layer has returned 100%, this layer is used.
- Points is generated from a CSV, add geometry to points has been performed and used.

  School latitude longitude
  1    5.5856567  50.5983856
  2    3.7947097  50.497005
  3    6.0334594  50.5937665
  4    2.8758204  50.4749299
  5    2.9487591  50.5603811

Being new to QGIS, I am trying `Vector < Data management tools < Join attributes by location`. This always returns "error: feature (xyz) has invalid geometry. Please fix or choose ignore". Ignore however leads to an empty dataset.

The layers come from the government, should be fine. The coordinates are generated by Google Maps. Other questions concerning joins address invalid layers and intersections. Layers have been validated here, no doubles exist, all points are within a layer.

Comment: Try verifying the geometry validity of your layers in `Vector -> geometry tools -> validity check` choose your layer and click run, it should add a layer with invalid geometries in your layer sections that you will have to correct

Comment: The validity check gives you two options for the checking algorithm. For me using QGIS 3.2 the "GEOS" method returns no invalid or error geometries, but the QGIS method returns 18 ERROR and 7 INVALID geometries.

Comment: Hicham: maybe I wasn't clear enough but this is exactly what I did. Returned 3 layers; error and invalid are empty. Valid contains the full layer.
Spacedman: I just tried with QGIS method and still all is in the valid layer.

Comment: SOLVED: a friend who works with QGIS pointed out 2 things:
1: make sure the CRS are equal.
2: QGIS 3.2 is not up to speed. His firm advises clients to stick with 2.18 atm. I tried to join the layers in wgs 84 same way, same files. Succes in 2.18, failure in 3.2.